# Nginx - Rewrite rule under proxy failed

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have some issues with a "basic" rewriting rule under a proxy_pass location type :

```html
location ~* /test1/network/v1/operator/ke3/dataUp {
              rewrite ^(?<begin>/test1/network/v1/operator/ke3/dataUp)(?<parametersPart>.*)(?<mustDie>/dataUp)$ $parametersPart break;
              proxy_pass http://server_preproduction;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
       }
```

I expect any calls sent to : `.../test1/network/v1/operator/ke3/dataUp?param1=GHJ&param2=865/dataUp`

To be equal to : `.../test1/network/v1/operator/ke3/dataUp?param1=GHJ&param2=865`

So I just want to parse the parameters section in order to remove any extra /dataUp from the original request.
But when I try to use any kind of regex to do so, nginx seems to return to the location / and use the default request...

I'm sure that the proper location is use, becanse when I use a rewrite like : `rewrite ^(?<begin>/test1/network/v1/operator/ke3/dataUp)(?<parametersPart>.*)$ TEST$parametersPart break;` 
The log on the proxy server received : TEST?param1=GHJ&param2=865/dataUp

I do not add a / at the end of the proxy_pass because I want replace all the url.(but it's not mandatory ! I tried lot of combinations...)

If someone can save my day :p

Thanks !!

Comment: Your `rewrite` statement will not work. The query string is not part of the [normalized URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) used to match `rewrite` and `location` directives.

Comment: @RichardSmith hey thanks for your response, but obvisouly I need more precision I read the documentation and try another type or URI, I catch the request but I can parse it "completly" during the rewrite. So the rewrite do something for example I can parse the first part of the URI / test1/network/v1/operator/ke3/dataUp and the second part with the arguments, but I can't parse the argument distinctly...

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to manipulate the argument with a simple if statement...

```
    if ($query_string ~ "^(?<argsok>/dataUp.*)(?<argsko>/dataUp)$") {
        proxy_pass http://server_preproduction/$argsok;
    }
```